# Using OpenCV with AWS Deep Learning AMI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv

I'm using [AWS Deep Learning AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/tutorial-conda.html) and I use environnement ***tensorflow_p27***.

I would like to use OpenCV lib so I install it from conda

```
conda install opencv
```

but when I try to import cv2, I got the error :

> ImportError: /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/../../libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so)

Note : When I try without environnement, it works perfectly, I tried to reinstall **libgcc** / change my **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** but nothing work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this is happening, but the following solution helped me. I do not remember where I have found it, it would be better to give that person the credit he/she deserves.

Rename that libstdc++.so.6 to libstdc++.so.6.bkp so that opencv uses the default file in the operating system other than conda file. It works like a charm in Ubuntu deep learning AMI. I have not tested it with Amazon AMI.

Command to rename is `mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bkp` while you are in the lib directory for that environment.

Comment: I tried your solution, it gave me the same error with an other file, i applied it the same transformation and it worked, thanks for you help. (I tried on the Amazon AMI)

Comment: I am glad to hear it helped, Best luck :)